# Error while exxecutiong query on Aws Athena DB, error Code : 100123

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbvisualizer

I have setup AWS Athena DB and and can access it using AWS web console.
select * from "Schema"."test_table" limit 10;

Its giving me 10 records as expected.

Then I have setup DBVisualizer database tool in EC2 instance in same VPC. Created a new Data Driver using driver manager for Athena access in DBVis.
Using : SimbaAthenaJDBC42.jar

and created a connection (AthenaConn) using the above created driver and below URL :

jdbc:awsathena://athena..amazonaws.com:443;s3_staging_dir=s3://<dir_of_queryResult>/;AwsCredentialProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProviderCredentialProvider;

"I am using InstanceProviderCredentialProvider , thats why I am not prividng db username and password (access/secret keys) while creating connection"

Connection successfully created and I can see My database and schema and and table has appeared in DBViz

- AthenaConn
  AwsDataCatalog
  default
  EXTERNAL_TABLE
  test_table

Now I am executing query on the test_table to select all records (Select * from "default"."test_table")

Error :
[Code:100123, SQL state: HY000] [Simba][AthenaJDBC][100123] An error has occured. Exception during column intialization. Details: null ( service :AthenaStreamingService; status code:403 , error Code : null; Request Id : nul; Proxy:proxy)[Execution Id : ...]

Note:
My Ec2 instace has IAM role with following polices attached
S3(full access),
fullAthenaAccess
AWSQuickSightAthenaAccess

Ec2 instace has SecurityGroup inbound rule (custom/TCP 444 port/ *.*.0.0/20) and same privaeVPCEndpoint securityGroup also has inbound rule open to 444 port (custom/TCP *.*.0.0/20)[* is a number in my case]

Comment: Have you verified if your IAM and security ports as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html#migration-from-previous-jdbc-driver ?

Comment: I have verified , all SG, policies and ports are enables as per doc, but still I am getting error